# Changing color of slider in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to change the color of my sliders in R shiny from blue to black and I was able to do it for the first one but I can't make it work for the others. It's probably because they are conditional so I'm not sure how to change the color of those. Could someone help me please? Here is my code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

MyData <- read.csv("/Users/s/Desktop/ShinyTest/ForShiny8.csv")

# Define UI ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PP",
                  titleWidth = 500),
  
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),    
    box(
      #change color to red
      status = "danger",width = 8,
      fluidRow(
        column(6,
               selectInput("DrillName1",
                           label = "Choose a Drill:",
                           choices = unique(MyData$Drill),
                           selected = NULL,
                           multiple = FALSE),
               
        ),
        column(6,
               sliderInput("slider1", 
                           label = ("Time in minutes"), 
                           min = 0, 
                           max = 60, 
                           value = 0),
        )
      ),
      
      fluidRow( 
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.num > '1'",
          column(6,  
                 selectInput("DrillName2",
                             label = "Choose a Drill:",
                             choices = unique(MyData$Drill),
                             selected = NULL,
                             multiple = FALSE),
          ),
          column(6,
                 
                 sliderInput("slider2", 
                             label = ("Time in minutes"), 
                             min = 0, 
                             max = 60, 
                             value = 0,
                             ),
          ),
        )
      ),
      
    #change color of slider
    setSliderColor(c("black"),c(1,2))
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic  ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

Since you have multiple sliders you need to chose a color for each id.

```
setSliderColor(c("black", "black"),c(1,2))
```

Alternatively, another approach if you want all sliders to be the same color is to use `shinyWidgets::chooseSliderSkin`. You can add that in your dashboardBody or fluidPage and set the color property to your choosing or even a different slider UI.